# What is the value of integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Confusion in the value of integral:

$$\int_{|z|=4}\frac{dz}{z^2-1}$$

Now $z^2-1=(z+1)(z-1)$

If I write the integral as 
$$\int_{|z|=4}\frac{f(z)dz}{z-1}, \text{ where } f(z)=\frac{1}{z+1}$$  Then by Cauchy integral formula I get $2\pi if(1)$ which is nothing but $\pi i$

But if I write the integral as $$\int_{|z|=4}\frac{g(z)dz}{z+1}, \text{ where } g(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$$  Then by Cauchy integral formula I get $2\pi ig(-1)$ which is $-\pi i$

I am confused.

Comment: In both of your two cases, the functions $f$ and $g$ are not analytic in the disk $|z|<4$(so you can not use Cauchy integral formula ). You can deal with this problem by $\frac{1}{z^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1})$.